# How to make ajax call url relative to js file directory

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, mono

For one site, Chrome and IE invoke ajax calls using urls without prepending
javascript file directory to url.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="/admin/pos.js?v=r2zPvjSAIOf2x8oTbPdUvRh9sFohBNwKM2QOVoOYSug1"></script>
.....
```

pos.js:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Registers/Test',
            timeout: 3 * 1000,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false
        });
```

Application is running by typing `http://1.2.3.4/admin/Sale` in browser url.

Chrome console shows that ajax calls are invoked using wrong url:

```
http://1.2.3.4/api/Registers/Test?_=1393704244572
```

How to force browser to use correct url by prepending admin to url:

```
http://1.2.3.4/admin/api/Registers/Test?_=1393704244572
```

Code above works for some sites but stopped work for one site where ip address 1.2.3.4
was used without dns name as in other sites and application is mapped to site root directory.
Application was changed as well and mono was upgraded to 3.2.8
No idea what caused browser to stop creating correct urls?

I'd prefer not to use base html element or use absolute url in javascript. Based on my understandig this code should work without them

ASP.NET MVC4 application is running in Mono 3.2.8 + mod_mono in Debian.

jquery is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the [UrlHelper.RouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505215%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method.

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
 url: '@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { controller = "Registers", action = "Test" })',
 ...
```

**EDIT:**
To generate the path to the javascript file you could use another helper:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/admin/pos.js")"></script>
```

**EDIT2**
Your best and probably the only solution is to pass the url as the js function's argument

Your function in pos.js:

```
function MyFunction(url)
{
  var xhr = $.ajax({
  url: url,
  ...
}
```

and then call it from the cshtml like:

```
MyFunction('@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { controller = "Registers", action = "Test" })');
```

Comment: javascript is stored is separate js file which is not processed by razor. How to enable js file processed by Razor?

Comment: index.cshtml file contains `@Scripts.Render("~/pos.js")` and this appears `<script src="/admin/pos.js?v=r2zPvjSAIOf2x8oTbPdUvRh9sFohBNwKM2QOVoOYSug1"></script>` in browser. pos.js is actually js bundle. If you think that generating absolute url solves the isse, how to generate it in this case ?

Comment: I tried `@Url.Content(Scripts.Render("~/pos.js"))` but got compile error. On different sites application may de installed to directoires other that admin, so admin cannto hard coded
`

Comment: I tried `<base href='/admin/' />`  but admin is still not added to ajax call url

Comment: So if @Scripts.Render("~/pos.js") generates /admin/pos.js, then do @Scripts.Render("~/api/pos.js"). I don't really understand what is the problem

Comment: The probles is that in js file ajax call `$.ajax({ url: '/api/Registers/Test'` invokes wrong url: it does not add `/admin/` to ajax url. It shoudl call  `/admin/api/Registers/Test`

Comment: Adding `var BASE_URL = '@Url.Content("~/")'` to index.cshtml and using in js file `url: BASE_URL + '/api/Registers/Test'` like in your answer fixes it. However it must work  without this. Application home directory `/admin` should automatically added. I asked why it does not work for new site. It worked other sites earlier but stops working in new site where application was changed and new Debian from scratch was installed. This issue occurs for some image fileas also, /admin is not added to igae url. Probably some simple setting causes browser not to add /admin to ajax urls.

Comment: @Andrus well, it depends on how your web server is configured and depends even on it's version. If you want to be sure, simply use the Urlhelper class and you will be fine ;)

Comment: In Apache `config sites-enabled/000-default` DocumentRoot was changed to `/var/www/store` . Other MVC4 application is root application. In earlier sites every MVC4 application was in separate subdirectoy. Don't believe this can be the issue, it looks like pure browser or jquery issue